# PHPMailer Could not instantiate mail function

Tags: php, email, phpmailer

I'm using simple code:

```
$mailer = new PHPMailer();
$mailer->IsMail();
$mailer->IsHTML(true);
$mailer->CharSet = 'utf-8';
$mailer->From = 'from@domain.com';
$mailer->Sender = $this->title;
$mailer->FromName = SITE_TITLE;
$mailer->Subject = $this->theme;
$mailer->Body = $this->text;
$mailer->AddAddress($this->mail);
$result = $mailer->Send();
```

Subject, Body, FromName, Sender are always the same. And it works with some email's, but it doesn't work with other emails with same domain names. For example, it works with email: some@mydomain.com, but it doesn't work with someAnother@mydomain.com
PHPMailer always send me errorinfo: Could not instantiate mail function.

With cmd i can send email on any address with the next command:

```
 echo "bla bla" | /usr/sbin/sendmail -f from@domain.com -v someAnother@mydomain.com -t -i
```

PHP INI:
sendmail_path = /usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i

PHP VER: 5.5
PHPMailer Ver: 5.2.7

I'll be greatful with any assistance!

Comment: Have you tried using `isSendmail()` instead of `isMail()`? In the sendmail command there should not be a space after `-f`.

Comment: What is in `$this->title`? It should be an email address, and will be what is used with the `-f` param because that's the envelope sender, not the from address.

Comment: isSendmail() not helping. Stay the same problem, but with another errorinfo: Could not execute: /usr/sbin/sendmail

Comment: That sounds like the same problem seen from a different place. Does your web server have exec permissions on sendmail?

Comment: I replaced $mailer->Sender = $this->title; with $mailer->Sender = 'from@domain.ru';  AND IT WORKS! Thank you!

Comment: I'll write that up as an answer if you'd be so kind as to accept it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `-f` in the sendmail command should not have a space between it and the sender address, so it should be `-ffrom@domain.com` not `-f from@domain.com`. This is built in to PHPMailer's command lines when it calls sendmail, so I doubt that's the problem.

The parameter that is passed to it is called the envelope sender and should be an email address (it's where bounces go). It does not have to be the same as the from address, but it often is. You are setting `$mailer->Sender = $this->title;` I suspect that what is in `$this->title` is not an email address.